# Can I define default type for text as keyword inside an object type?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-6

Let's say I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id":       {"type": "keyword"},
                "params":   {
                    "type": "object",
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`params` has a lot of fields with numeric and textual values. I don't want to specify all the fields of it but I would like to specify that all the text fields should be of `keyword` type instead of `text` which is the default and is analysed (which I want to avoid).

How can I do this? I'm using ElasticSearch 6.7

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Updated. I'm using 6.7

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adding to what [@banuj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120147/banuj) mentioned:

It seems that it is possible to combine [`match_mapping_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html#match-mapping-type) and [`path_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) to achieve what I wanted.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "keyword params": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "path_match": "params.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is called Dynamic Templates (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/dynamic-templates.html)

For your question you can define the mapping as follows:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This transforms all the detected `string` fields to `keyword`. If you want to apply only to a subset of fields, you can use `match`, `unmatch`, `path_match` or `path_unmatch` clauses. (See the docs for differences between them).

Comment: Thanks! I've added my own answer for completeness to filter both by path and by type (string).